# KMZ file not showing by geoxml3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-earth, kmz

I am using **geoxml3** to parse my Kmz files but its not doing anything i have downloaded the script

```
**https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3**
```

from here.
I have an input field where user can upload kmz file when file is uploaded and presses button only map shows nothing else :

```
 <input class="button-d" onclick="initMap2()" type="submit" value="Embed Kmz" style="float: right" />

<input type="file" id="file" name="file">
```

**script.js**

```
var input=document.getElementById("file").files[0]
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-19.257753, 146.823688),
        zoom: 2,
        mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });
    console.log(input)//console for file is successful 
    var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({map: map, singleInfoWindow: true});
    geoXml.parse(input)
    //geoXml.parse('C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/example.kmz  
    //even the above commented statement doesn't work
```

Comment: What browser(s)? What errors do you get in the javascript console?

Comment: @geocodezip i am getting zero errors

Comment: @geocodezip if i use KmLayer and upload my file to drive, and assigning it works fine, but using geoxml3 nothing happens

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: @geocodezip above example demonstrates my issue

Comment: @geocodezip can you view this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45931091/kmz-files-showing-nothing-via-geoxml3